# TPROXY for redirecting UDP on arbitrary ports

Tags: iptables, udp

I want to intercept all UDP traffic leaving tap1. And possibly reply to e.g. DNS-requests. To accomplish this I wrote some python code listening to localhost and use *iptables* with a rule-set like this:

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 2 packets, 333 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination   

    0     0 DIVERT     udp  --  tap1   any     anywhere             anywhere             socket
    0     0 TPROXY     udp  --  tap1   any     anywhere             anywhere             TPROXY redirect 127.0.0.1:5001 mark 0x1/0x1


Chain DIVERT (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 MARK       udp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             MARK set 0x1
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere
```

Policy routing is done with:

```
ip rule add fwmark 1 lookup 100
ip route add local 0.0.0.0/0 dev lo table 100
```

This setup was adapted from the kernel's Documentation/networking/tproxy.txt.
This works flawlessly for a TCP socket opened with the IP_TRANSPARENT option.

Unfortunately UDP sockets don't seem to be able to handle connections. For example if I do a `ncat -u localhost 1234` the socket will receive data but cannot send anything back. Wireshark will show exactly three packets for:

1. the incoming ncat packet (to localhost:1234)
2. the outgoing packet of my software (to :5001)
3. an ICMP Port unreachable (of course)

For arbitrary ports to work I guess it's not feasable to set up proper (S)NATting rules.

So, what's the necessary setup to make this work for *arbitrary* incoming ports?